# How To Install Laravel Cashier in Laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel

I'm installing Laravel Cashier in Laravel 5.8 using composer but I'm getting an error message

**Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.**

I use this command to install cashier

**composer require laravel/cashier**

[image]

please help to install a cashier using composer

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to install laravel/cashier 11.2 which isn't compatible with Laravel 5.8. To resolve this you will need to install an earlier version of laravel/cashier, try version 10, or upgrade your Laravel App to the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

following worked for me

```
composer require laravel/cashier:*
```